# Постановка тире в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли тире. "Рецептура масла лавандового, % к массе масла: спиртовые эфиры – 100,0; масляная кислота – 1,0; уксусная кислота – 1,5; вода (–) по расчёту". (Тире в неполном предложении?). И после цифр лучше оставить ; или поставить запятые?

Comment: Кого оставить, точки с запятой?

Comment: Да, точку с запятой.

Comment: _"% к массе масла" (?)_ === По-моему, что-то тут не то! Во всяком случае я, наверное, по этому рецепту вряд ли сумел бы что-либо приготовить. Правильно ли я понимаю: для приготовления, к примеру, 100 г масла лавандового предлагается взять 100 г спиртовых эфиров, 1 г масляной кислоты, полтора грамма уксусной кислоты плюс какое-то количество воды?

Comment: Я не химик, попросили уточнить. Возможно, имеется в виду нужно ли ставить тире и точки с запятыми в предложениях такого типа. За содержание предложения ответить не могу.

Comment: _Стася: нужно ли ставить тире и точки с запятыми_ === Ну, если вопрос только в этом, то да, нужны и тире, и точки с запятой. При наличии чисел типа "100,0", "1,0", "1,5" запятая в перечислении ингредиентов плохо смотрится: *_кислота – 1,5, вода...(?)_

Comment: Да, согласна с Вами и про точки с запятой и про тире. Нужно было подтверждение. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы тире оставил. Ну а почему нет, "по расчету" - тоже своего рода число, только переменное. Как Икс в математике.